# Best way to control large buck converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

I am looking for a faster way to control output voltage for a buck converter.
This buck converter has its own fet driver and I am not willing to change it. I really only need the signal to run the gate driver.

A little about the project

60 khz

0-100 percent duty cycle

voltage adjustment 0-5v , my MCU will be making adjustments to the "target voltage" that I need something to aim for.  For various reasons I can only use an analog 0-5v out to make these adjustments, digital wont work.

current limiting, would be nice, but not necessary.

600 volt input about 350v output

I am currently using the arduino to figure out duty cycle, but would like another way to figure out the duty cycle so the arduino only has to set the target voltage instead of trying to monitor current ect.

Still on the fence if the next version will be low or high side, if it matters I can go either way.

How should I go about this?

Or am I better off building it out of a big mess of timers and op amps

[image]

Any advice greatly appreciated

Comment: Please pose this question as a design question.

Comment: please also write a title which accurately summarises your question

Comment: That's an impressive piece of equipment !!!

Comment: You are trying to do some things in ways whose reasons are uncertain and which may be suboptimal. It would help if you can provide an overall circuit diagram AND a complete specification of the aims. ie the level of detail that you would have needed to attempt to design this. // The suggestion  "big mess of timers and opamps" indicates that you may not have a good feel for the potential severity of such a task and the capabilities than an appropriate IC can give. || By no means complete questions. Why decication to specific gate driver, and what is it? Why 60 kHz . Power? More ...?

Comment: Some more information on your control method and why it's not performing the way you want it to might also help. Is it current or voltage mode controlled? You implied it's current mode controlled but it's worth asking to verify. What is the crossover frequency of your controller? Any other info you can share would help.

Comment: How about a dedicated PMIC with I2C or SPI interface for setting the output voltage?

Comment: "Why dedication to specific gate driver?" because Im not interested in having 50 different gate drivers when 3 will cover all my needs present and future. I am not a professional and I dont do this full time. I only have a few MB upstairs and arent going to waste them on mastering 10 of the same thing. 60 khz because the inductors perform well there, arduino outputs 60 khz easily, and from experience higher frequencies bring a whole other set of problems with noise. I originally asked about suitable IC but the post got deleted, apparently its against the rules?

Comment: Its voltage controlled and I want to stick with that.   The controller runs at 10 khz, works great for dumping excess electricity into a heating element, but when summer rolls around I want to be putting that power into the DC bus of the VFD drive that runs my air conditioning and I dont think thats fast enough. I2C or SPI is probably better, but I have tons of things more important to learn first, so ill stick with analog.

Comment: I have spent many hours searching for a buck IC, but there all tiny and drivers built in. I think what I need is called something else, but I dont know what that is. Im sure its out there since when someone drives a fet the size of a brick they obviously arent using a all in one chip. It would be exactly what I am looking for, a somewhat generic controller/feedback loop that runs a driver suited to the fet.   This isnt the last buck converter I will build, and I want to find a good solution that I can use for all my buck converters going forward.

Comment: A better search term may be eg DC DC switching **controller**. || Here are many such as Digikey. https://www.digikey.co.nz/short/pbmb8m07 . || Many of the ICs used in offline power supplies since forever are potentially suitable. They operate relative to ground with the expectation of driving a high voltage switch. || Examples only are the UC384x family. || A search on offline buck or UC384? etc offline turns up much - some may even be useful :-). ||

Comment: This looks very promising - [A low-cost, non-isolated AC/DC buck
converter with no transformer](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt391/slyt391.pdf?ts=1705574034557&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). Off mains but easiy upscaled and up powered and driver can be exchanged for your one.

Comment: This need not know that it's not an LED light on the hot end :-) https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mp4001.html